# Partially mocking a module

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I have the following file I would like to test

`functions.js`:

```js
function funcOne() {
  return funcTwo();
}

function funcTwo() {
  return 'func two';
}

module.exports = {
  funcOne,
  funcTwo
};
```

I want to mock the funcTwo so that it returns me different string when called through my `functions.funcOne`

`functions.test.js`:

```js
function mockFunctions() {
  const original = require.requireActual('./functions');
  return {
    ...original, // Pass down all the exported objects
    funcTwo: jest.fn(() => {
      return 'my test func';
    })
  };
}
jest.mock('./functions', () => mockFunctions());
const functions = require.requireMock('./functions');

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  console.log(functions.funcOne());
});
```

It still prints me 'func two' instead of 'my test func'.

Is there a way to leave the module intact and just mock one particular method?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

`functions.js`:

```js
function funcOne() {
  return exports.funcTwo();
}

function funcTwo() {
  return 'func two';
}

exports.funcOne = funcOne;
exports.funcTwo = funcTwo;
```

Unit test:

`functions.spec.js`

```js
const functions = require('./functions');

describe('functions test suites', () => {
  it('funcOne', () => {
    const funcTwoSpyOn = jest.spyOn(functions, 'funcTwo').mockReturnValueOnce('my test func');
    const actualValue = functions.funcOne();
    expect(actualValue).toBe('my test func');
    expect(funcTwoSpyOn).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    funcTwoSpyOn.mockRestore();
  });
  it('funcTwo', () => {
    const actualValue = functions.funcTwo();
    expect(actualValue).toBe('func two');
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/53889291/functions.spec.js
  functions test suites
    ✓ funcOne (5ms)
    ✓ funcTwo

--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File          |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files     |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 functions.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.199s
```

Here is the completed demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/53889291